# How to detect if a video has been loaded in Media Player Framework?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to detect if video has been loaded and ready to play in Media Player Framework?

(http://playerframework.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to listen to `PlayerStateChanged` event of `MediaPlayer` control. Then check if `PlayerState` is `Loaded`.

Refer to the official documentation of Microsoft Media Platform Player Framework :

- [MediaPlayer](http://smf.blob.core.windows.net/docs/win8/xaml/api/html/AllMembers_T_Microsoft_PlayerFramework_MediaPlayer.htm)
- [PlayerState](http://smf.blob.core.windows.net/docs/win8/xaml/api/html/AllMembers_T_Microsoft_PlayerFramework_PlayerState.htm)
- [PlayerStateChanged](http://smf.blob.core.windows.net/docs/win8/xaml/api/html/E_Microsoft_PlayerFramework_MediaPlayer_PlayerStateChanged.htm)